# How to make Spring Boot use MultiTenantSpringLiquibase?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, liquibase

In my Spring Boot application, I want Liquibase to create tables on a PostgreSQL database, so in my configuration classes, I have set up a Bean that returns a [MultiTenantSpringLiquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/javadoc/liquibase/integration/spring/MultiTenantSpringLiquibase.html) containing schema names that it should use.

The problem is that this Bean is created but ignored, Spring Boot finds a valid SpringLiquibase Bean in LiquibaseAutoConfiguration, and uses it on my DB, accessing the same changelog that I intended for MultiTenantSpringLiquibase. This fails because this configuration tries to use the schema "public", which does not exist. If it does exist, it creates the tables I've defined in my changelog, but I don't want them to appear in the "public" schema.

How do I prevent LiquibaseAutoConfiguration or SpringLiquibase from executing, so that my MultiTenantSpringLiquibase Bean is used instead ?

Comment: I do this last month, but i'm att home now. Monday ill answer here.

Comment: Try this code sample: https://gist.github.com/cavarzan/3134363a293f18fbe4cddce208e7df29

Comment: You can skip the default schema and only execute the migration in the other schemas. If Works i post as a answer

Comment: Can you provide us your bean definition of MultiTenantSpringLiquibase? Since this class implements the InitializingBean interface, Spring should invoke the afterPropertiesSet method right after adding the bean to the application context. What happens when you set a debugger breakpoint into this method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your application.properties, add this.

```
spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration
```

or in your Main class use this.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude={LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.class})
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! I wonder why it was so hard to find, maybe because of the combination MultiTenantSpringLiquibase and Spring Boot, and the specific need of using only multitenant with no "common" schema.

Answer (score 5):

You should have at least the `SpringLiquibase` bean for the default schema.
In this case, you can skip the execution for this bean, but need to declare it.

```
@Bean
public SpringLiquibase liquibase(@Qualifier("taskExecutor") TaskExecutor taskExecutor,
                                     DataSource dataSource, LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties) {
     SpringLiquibase liquibase = new AsyncSpringLiquibase(taskExecutor, env);
     liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
     liquibase.setChangeLog("path-to-xml");
     liquibase.setContexts(liquibaseProperties.getContexts());
     liquibase.setDefaultSchema(liquibaseProperties.getDefaultSchema());
    return liquibase;
}
```

After this configuration, you should be able to create the `MultiTenantSpringLiquibase` Bean to run in all schemas:

```
@Bean
@DependsOn("liquibase") // ensure execution after SpringLiquibase Bean
public MultiTenantSpringLiquibase liquibaseMt(DataSource dataSource, LiquibaseProperties liquibaseProperties) {

    MultiTenantSpringLiquibase liquibase = new MultiTenantSpringLiquibase();

    liquibase.setDataSource(dataSource);
    liquibase.setChangeLog("path-to-xml");
    liquibase.setDefaultSchema(YOUR_DEFAULT_SCHEMA);
    liquibase.setSchemas(YOUR_ARRAY_OF_SCHEMAS);
    return liquibase;
}
```

After the execution of the `SpringLiquibase`, `MultiTenantSpringLiquibase` will be called and executed in your schemas by the line `liquibase.setSchemas(...)`

This sample is a working sample that I've used recently.

Full example class [here](https://gist.github.com/cavarzan/3134363a293f18fbe4cddce208e7df29).

Comment: This is a valid answer and I was able to set up a SpringLiquibase Bean with "shouldRun=false", but in my case, since I do not use the default schema at all, I prefer to use Jade Devin Nocum Cabatlao's solution, which answers my specific issue more precisely (make Spring Boot use only MultiTenantSpringLiquibase and avoid running anything on the default schema).
Thank you for making me understand how this works.

Comment: Sure! Indeed I also exclude de LiquebaseAutoConfig from my App class! Let's keep this answer that may help someone else.

Comment: Cannot get this working: always get an error on the first schema that gets created. Error: table already excists for tenant1.tablename... I am trying to make a  Jhipster multi tenant application

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding this to your application.properties file:

```
#Disable Liquibase
spring.liquibase.enabled=false
```

If you don't disable it I believe this gets executed:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration.java#L74

It's just an idea, I'm not sure but you can try since you have the environment and I can only speculate.

Comment: I tried a few times, this property does prevent the unwanted SpringLiquibase from being executed, but it seems that my MultiTenantSpringLiquibase is also disabled by this. I am trying to understand the mechanism that "executes" the chosen Liquibase config on the DB, because I'm not sure if I'm correctly assuming that my tables should be created without additional config. I'll add details when I have more.
Maybe a MWE is needed, but in that case it would require Spring Boot, a database and a Configuration class using MultiTenantSpringLiquibase.